# Перевод "The duplicate question must exist on StackOverflow"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При попытке закрыть вопрос, ссылаясь на отличный от ru.SO ресурс выдается следующее сообщение:

[image: ru.SO]

На мой взгляд, этот перевод неточен, поскольку на en.SO аналогичное сообщение выглядит так:

[image: en.SO]

Тем самым однозначно определяя, что дубликат **должен** находиться на SO, а не **может**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Спасибо за сообщение. Вы правы, это ошибка в переводе.

Я отредактировал перевод, со следующим обновлением строк должно исправиться.

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, ещё строку "possible duplicate of ...", которая вставляется в комментарий о том, что вопрос является дубликатом. Вариант перевода: "Возможно, этот вопрос является дубликатом вопроса ...". Не стесняйтесь использовать другой вариант, если он придёт вам в голову, в этом мне не нравится повторение слова "вопрос", но сформулировать по другому у меня не получается.

Comment: @fori1ton: А где этот текст встречается? Можете сделать скриншот?

Comment: Это комментарий, который добавляется автоматически при рекомендации вопроса к закрытию как повторяющегося. К сожалению, после закрытия вопроса этот комментарий удаляется, а сейчас в очереди проверок нет ни одного вопроса-дубликата, так что со скриншотом придётся подождать.

Comment: Если всё ещё актуально, то вот скриншот: http://i.imgur.com/U3n3SUr.png

Comment: @fori1ton: Хм, его нету среди локализуемых строк. Ну по крайней мере в транзифексе. Так что надо пингануть Николаса.